# CSS selectors, getting inconsistent behaviour

Tags: html, css

I am in a context of a markdown editor, and came across some inconsistency regarding CSS selectors. Refer to the 4 cases below.

#### CASE 1:

```css
.mytable tr th {
    color: brown;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>TITLE</th>
    <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It works as expected i.e. makes `border-width` equal to  `0` as intended. My question is why do the following CSS Style don't equivalently work.

#### CASE 2:

```css
tr th {
    color: brown;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>TITLE</th>
    <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Shouldn't it globally apply to any table? I mean it applies to font, but leaves out `border-width` effect.

#### CASE 3:

```css
.mytable tr, th {
    color: brown;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>TITLE</th>
    <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What about this one? Why doesn't this apply to border, but still affects fonts?

#### CASE 4:

```css
.mytable th {
    color: brown;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>TITLE</th>
    <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Neither does this one apply to borders. So, how do these case actually work, why don't they affect `border-width`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? For me they all look the same.  Try a different browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your question to have runnable snippets, and as you can see, all of them are working. If in your local codebase only `.mytable tr th` is applying, it means there is a specificity issue. It means there is a CSS selector that has a higher specificity than `tr th`, and `.mytable tr, th`, and `.mytable th`, and lower than `.mytable tr th` that's setting the `border-width`.

> Specificity is the algorithm used by browsers to determine the CSS declaration that is the most relevant to an element, which in turn, determines the property value to apply to the element. The specificity algorithm calculates the weight of a CSS selector to determine which rule from competing CSS declarations gets applied to an element. More on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: I am using these in a markdown editor. So, as I understand I need to specific about styles i.e. `.mytable tr th` overrides the `mytable tr` or,  `mytable tr th` styles?

Comment: Yeah `.mytable tr th` overrides `.mytable tr` or `.mytable tr th`.

Comment: Okay, I'll accept your answer since it provides explanation on what was happening. So I think its my markdown editor's pre-loaded template that's conflicting with styles.

Comment: Yeah probably, as markdown comes with its own conventional styles.